# Assign virtual core number to specific real core

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu, cpu-frequency

Is there any way to assign ''linux core numbers'' to specific real cores?

I'm working with an asymmetric architecture, so not all cores are the same, and I want to assign specific cores number to each core.

Suppose my processor has 6 cores, two of them of type ARM-A57 and the other fours of type ARM-A53, and I want to map the cpu0, cpu1 (linux virtual cores) with the ARM-57 cores, and cpu2-cpu5 to the ARM-53 cores.

At this moment, kernel 4.2.0 assigns cpu0, cpu3-cpu5 to ARM-53 cores, and cpu1-cpu2 to ARM-57 cores (no sense).

Comment: I think `cpu0` is the CPU that Linux boots from. If so it may still be possible to get the A53's to be `cpu0` through `cpu3` and the A57's to be `cpu4` and `cpu5`.